Weird data showing on the Web Power BI
I have a orign that is a call from an API and on the desktop the data make sense and it's everything ok, BUT, when i publish the dashboard and the data updates some weird data appairs. Data that doenst even exists.
PBI Desktop:

PBI Web:

I'm kinda lost of what more information i can give, becouse that's extremely bizarre... So if you have any hint in mind, let me know!

I figured it out. Both the desktop and the server uses the pt-br regional settings, but when the data updates on the server the configuration that i made on the field become kinda lost and some times uses the american pattern and some times the pt-br pattern.
The solution was change on the data source the type and not just on the model.
